# send image from mysql server to node js template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL server in node js and want to show that data on ejs template. I know this is a very basic thing, I am very new to node js, this is my first project on node js.

**in my app.js**

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : 'password',
            database : 'automator'
          });
          connection.connect(function(err){
               if(err) throw err;
               console.log("connected");
               });
               var sql = "SELECT * FROM wallpaper LIMIT 10";
               connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log("result of top 10 querys"+result)
               var rows = JSON.stringify(result);
               res.render('pages/allevent',{rows: JSON.parse(rows)});
                    });


**in allevent.ejs**

  <% for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) { %>
  <tr>
       <td><%= rows[i].EventName %></td>
       <td><img class="custom-image logo" src="./public/"<%= rows[i].LaptopImage.name %> alt="" title="" width="100px"/></td>

  </tr>
<% } %>
```

I am able to access eventname but, image is not showing .
instead of url some number are showing like `116,104,114,101,101,46,106,112,103`

Please help me solve this

Comment: What are 'some number'? Can You provide the example of that? What is the structure of Your project and wallpaper entities?

Comment: I getting like 116,104,114,101,101,46,106,112,103 116,104.

Comment: @KarlR In node js function I am also getting this blob data but there I am converting to string